# How can two negative lookaheads be used in a regex with a word boundary?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex that allows me to find multiple URLs within a string. It has two negative lookaheads, '<<' and '.onion'.

Currently the first lookahead works as expected, it prevents a match if the URL ends in '<<'. The second ('.onion') does not work properly, it prevents the entire line before it from matching if found.

PCRE:

```
(?i)\b(?!.*?\.onion)
(?>
(?:
    [a-z][\w-]+:
    (?:
        /{1,3}
      |
        [a-z0-9%]
    )
  |
    ftp://
  |
    www\d{0,3}[.]
  |
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/
)
(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+?(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))\b(?!<<)
```

If i move the second lookahead to the end it continues to behave strangely, matching the URL it is supposed to ignore while still not matching the genuine URLs before it.

Example string (intended matches in bold):

**www.google.com** **http://wikipedia.org** www.google.com<<

**www.google.com** http://wikipedia.org<< **www.google.com**

www.google.com<< **http://wikipedia.org www.google.com**

**www.google.com http://wikipedia.org** www.google.onion

[Link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vB0wX9/2)

I asked a similar question recently and the current expression has developed from that.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. A suggestion: 1) build a simple and naive pattern to find urls in text (nothing complicated, it's useless), put it in an atomic group and add `(?!<<)` after. 2) for each result, use `parse_url` to extract the path, and check if it doesn't end with `.onion`. (Note: you can use `filter_var` to check if the match is really an URL)

Comment: Try [`(?i)\b(?!\S+\.onion\b)(?>(?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|ftp://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+?(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*?\)|[^\s\`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))\b(?!<<)`](https://regex101.com/r/vB0wX9/4) - But! it is a very poor pattern. Please consider reconsidering the approach :)

Comment: Would it be far better then for me to ditch both negative lookaheads and use the parse_url method to check for dodgy URLS?